# How to make this start every time I start the computer?

Tags: scripts

I'm using a backlit keyboard and need to enter this every I start the computer.

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ -f /tmp/keyboard_light ]; then
xset -led 3 && rm /tmp/keyboard_light
else
xset led 3 && touch /tmp/keyboard_light
fi
```

How do I make it to start every time I start my computer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy the code into a text editor and save it somewhere as a .sh file (shell script).  Give the file execute permissions (Right click->Properties->Permissions Tab->Allow executing file as program).  Then, open up "Startup applications", add a new entry, click Browse and select the .sh file you created.  Hit save, reboot, and test.

If this doesn't work you can try adding `sleep 15` to the file, right after the !/bin/bash line to make it wait 15 seconds after logging in in before running.